# Magento 2: Product zoom magnifier is not working properly

Tags: magento2, product-images, zoom, magnifier

I have used deafult Magento's product zoom magnifier on our website and want to show the zoom window within the image container but its not working properly. Its not zooming well and I'm not sure what am I missing here. Below is the code I'm using:

```
<var name="magnifier">
                <var name="fullscreenzoom">200</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
                <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
                <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
                <var name="width">1000</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
                <var name="height">1000</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
                <var name="eventType">hover</var>
                <var name="enabled">true</var>
                <var name="mode">inside</var>
        </var>
```

Can anyone please me on this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change magnifier-preview img properties as:
.magnifier-preview img (or #preview img) {
max-width: unset;
max-height: unset;
width: unset !important;
height: unset !important;
}

Max zoom is 50% in magnifier.js , if i'm not mistaken.